# Как убрать полоски в option?

Tags: html, css, css3

Как убрать полоски в option?

Две полоски, одна снизу другая с левой стороны.

http://jsfiddle.net/chech/u5rcheqf/1/

```
<style>
select option { padding:5px 0px; }
</style>    
<select>
<option>&nbsp;1</option>
<option>&nbsp;2</option>
<option>&nbsp;3</option> 
</select>

<br/>
<br/>
option with no left padding:
<br/>

<style>
select option { padding:5px 0px; }
</style>    
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option> 
</select>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не могли бы вы сделать скриншот, не понятно о каких полосках идет речь.

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian вставил.

Comment: Похоже на особенность рендера браузера/ОС. Не смог повторить в Chrome 49. Возможно вам подойдет javascript решение (кастомный select).

Answer (score 3):

Судя по всему это особенности браузера, либо вы не описали часть стилей, в моем браузере не воспроизводится (Chrome 48).
Похожий вопрос уже был, посмотрите здесь:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select